# how to avoid firefox to add overlay color on image click?

Tags: html, css, firefox, selection

take a look please:

[image]

The azure one is just clicked. Firefox only. It's just an `<img>` inside a `<li>`, no links. Why the hell does it becomes azure?? It's the first time in almost 20 years of web programming I see this. It seems to have nothing to do with ::selection, nor tap highlight, so I can't find a useful css rule to stop it. Firebug shows nothing meaningfull on the styles analisys panel. Also it's the only element in the page that behave this way. So what the hell is it? How to avoid?

Comment: Try [`user-select:none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select) but can you create a snippet for this?

Comment: Hi! user-select did the job! I didn't tried it yet because in theory it should not  address this thing, since it should be for drag-related events (as text selection), not click, and also it's not standard at all, as for your MDN link. Anyway, thank you. If you want, write a real answer and I'll mark it accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid it using [`user-select: none;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select)

> The text of the element and sub-elements will not be able to be selected

**Note**

> This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track